# How to correctly setup type guards for conditionally wrapping values

Tags: typescript

I'm having a lot of trouble find the correct syntax to cleanly wrap something in some wrapper type if it's not wrapped already.

What follows is the **spirit** of what I'm trying to do. I understand why this doesn't work, and it's just a reference.

I've been hacking at this for a while now, and I just can't find the correct combination of syntax for `asWrapped<>`, `isWrapped()` and `wrap()` that would make this work without having to resort to <strike>explicit casting</strike> type assertions.

```js
class Wrapper<ValT> {
    data: ValT;
    constructor(d: ValT) {
        this.data = d;
    }
}

type asWrapped<T> = T extends Wrapper<infer U> ? Wrapper<U> : Wrapper<T>;

const isWrapped = <T,>(what: T | Wrapper<T>): what is Wrapper<T> => {
    return (what as Wrapper<T>).data !== undefined;
}

const wrap = <T,>(v: T): asWrapped<T> => {
    if(isWrapped(v)) {
        return v;
    }
    else {
        return new Wrapper(v);
    }
}

const x = wrap(12);
const y = wrap(new Wrapper(12));
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOaXlm)

Comment: Hmm, @Oblosys's answer works without trying to do the impossible task of returning a generic conditional type.  Cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `wrap` type checks if you leave out the return signature and add  `| Wrapper<T>` to the parameter, I don't think you need the conditional type. The explicit cast in `isWrapped` can be taken care of by using a combination of `typeof what` and `'data' in what`, which would leave the following type-correct definitions (after also converting to expressions):

```
class Wrapper<ValT> {
    data: ValT;
    constructor(d: ValT) {
        this.data = d;
    }
}

const isWrapped = <T,>(what: T | Wrapper<T>): what is Wrapper<T> =>
  typeof what === 'object' ? 'data' in what : false

const wrap = <T,>(v: T | Wrapper<T>) => isWrapped(v) ? v : new Wrapper(v)

const x = wrap(12); // Wrapper<number>
const y = wrap(new Wrapper(12)); //Wrapper<number>
```

You could declare an `unwrap` like this, which infers the right types and has the intended runtime behavior:

```
const unwrap = <T,>(what: T | Wrapper<T>) =>
  isWrapped(what) ? what.data : what

const unwrapped = [unwrap(1), unwrap(x), unwrap(y)] as const
// inferred type: readonly [1, number, number]

console.log(unwrapped)
// output: [1, 12, 12]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8A1MIAqAfNAN4BQ0F0AJmAC5gBc0O+A3OZcAPYB2Et8AK7BaXeAAoqTFngCUJDpUq0AFgEsIAOhr1oAXmrslAX1KnS3PrWgaEyNFX3QMeADQFxAdxV0meaAA+cIgo6C4EskzedDYwdqGYhPoEHLQAnmhcAGbQ0dZ6BdAA5FwARgBWqCJF0AD8xTpgNWo8uT7WTFm4EKikFrz8uSFOLu7iAG5+gcH2YYTyekS2IQ4T8vXj0Ew8qJ4zCWt9loMAHk6eIeIAjABMsqzQAPSP+2iYPIIAtqXoKcfWaXOlx2e3ib2ud3uT0eYLCH2+vyOA2sgh4F2QIzcHjyUyCsMSEWSHGWsyoXna6zadG0dDAWyptCRVmgqPRoUcBgA2qzLldZK4WWjLid+YK2eI0rIALrQSDQf6kZ42HhZdDwVCOdJoJjqsBUXggQGcq4C+E-eCmr7mqVMiBcECoTQgLgAc3EPNJskVLy4gloSD9TGNAtuIZuNqAA)

Comment: @Frank Ah yes, missed that one, let me update it.

Comment: Really cool, thanks! It doesn't *quite* drop in as neatly in my actual project, but I'll be able to take it from there.